# Need to Display images from another server using PHP and SSH2_CONNECT

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.6, php-7.2

Am trying to display image from another server to the dashboard using PHP. I am able to get the file names in the directory and authentication is a success. But unable to view that image using src.

```
<?PHP
$connection = ssh2_connect('servername', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$handle  = opendir('ssh2.sftp://' . intval($sftp) . '/path/');
while (false != ($entry = readdir($handle))){
echo "$entry\n";
echo '<img src="ssh2.sftp://' . intval($sftp) . '/path/'.$entry.'">'; // Not working

}
?>
```

Comment: you can't view image from another server with ssh like that, you need to download that image to your server and show them

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<img src="ssh2.sftp://' . intval($sftp) . '/path/'.$entry.'">'; // Not working
```

This line didn't work because the `src` will be load **client side**, so, it's the client who will ask for `ssh2.sftp` connexion, and he can't do that.

You have to set `src` to a **public url**, usually an url from your server.

So the good way, like was say by [Surya Mahadi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61423827/need-to-display-images-from-another-server-using-php-and-ssh2-connect#comment108658500_61423827) it's to download the file. 
If you don't want to store the image, you can encode it in [base64](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.base64-encode.php) and send it like that.

For more information about `ssh2.sftp`, read the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ssh2-sftp.php).